# Suppress 'The variable is assigned but never used', when cache Start-Process Handle

Tags: powershell, exit-code, start-process

Is it possible to hide the PSScriptAnalyzer messeage in Visual studio code "The variable is assigned but never used"  ?

I tried with: `[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUserDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments')]`
But then the handle is not cached, and I cant get an exitcode

Code:

```
        $SplatArgs = @{
        FilePath    = $FilePath
        NoNewWindow = $true
        Passthru    = $true
        ErrorAction = "Stop"
    }

 $Execute = Start-Process @SplatArgs
        [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUserDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments')]
        $Handle = $Execute.Handle
        $Execute.WaitForExit()
```

The code is working fine, it's just the error message I want gone, initially I got the idea from :

[Obtaining ExitCode using Start-Process and WaitForExit instead of -Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262231/obtaining-exitcode-using-start-process-and-waitforexit-instead-of-wait)

[How to silence a warning or even better if you know why: is assigned but never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126151/how-to-silence-a-warning-or-even-better-if-you-know-why-is-assigned-but-never)

Comment: It should be `$Handle = $Execute.Handle`, not `$Handle = Execute.Handle`. Is it a typo on your side  ?

Comment: Anyway, `$Execute.Handle | Out-Null` instead of `$Handle = $Execute.Handle` should do the trick, as there is no more assignation (as the workaround only requires `Handle` property to be referenced).

Comment: Yes typo, your suggestion works perfectly, can't believe i didn't try that myself - thanks